# Array of fields of type bool

Tags: c#

I have 4 fields of type bool:

```
private bool f1;
public bool F1 {
get{return this.f1;}
set
 {
 this.f1=value;
 onPropertyChanged("F1");
 }
}

private bool f2;
public bool F2 {
get{return this.f2;}
set
 {
  this.f2=value;
  onPropertyChanged("F2");
 }
}
private bool f3;
public bool F3 {
get{return this.f3;}
set
 {
 this.f3=value;
 onPropertyChanged("F3");
 }
}
private bool f4;
public bool F4 {
get{return this.f4;}
set
 {
  this.f4=value;
  onPropertyChanged("F4");
 }
}
```

Only one of them can be true. I want a way to set them in a for loop. I tried the following:

```
bool[] myFields =
{
    F1,F2,F3,F4
};

int Answer = 1; 
for (int index = 0; index < myFields.Length; index++)
{
    if(index == Answer)
    {
        myFields[index] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        myFields[index] = false;
    }
}
```

but this will only set the value in the myFields array to true/false and not the Property F2 itself. Any ideas on how to make this nicer / working ?

Comment: I would suggest using an enum instead.

Comment: hi...could you please provide an example ?? how would enum works with this?

Comment: I posted an answer with a brief sample of how an enum would handle this.

Answer (score 4):

I think you don't want auto-properties here. How about this:

```
public bool F1 {
    get { return myFields[0]; }
    set { myFields[0] = value; }
}
etc...
```

?

Incidentally, your `for` loop could be simplified to:

```
for (int index = 0; index < myFields.Length; index++) {
     myFields[index] = (index == Answer);
}
```

Comment: hi ...i will give it a try.... but i need to register the onPropertyChanged then to catch any changes in the myFields right ?

Comment: @lebhero I don't understand, you'll have to give more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: ok, i need to set everytime all the Properties to false..only one of them should be true...so 
instead of making this:
F1=false;F2=true;F3=False;F4=false; 
i want this to be done in a for loop...

Comment: In that case you might want to remove the `set`er. But I don't see what that has to do with `onPropertyChanged`.

Comment: sorry my fault ...question was not clear enough ..i edited it above please check the question again

Answer (score 4):

This might be better handled with an `enum`. This way you can allow the values F1, F2, F3, F4 (and a "None", if applicable). Here's what that would look like:

```
public enum FValue { None, F1, F2, F3, F4 }

public class Foo
{
    public FValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the `[Flags]` tag, if (eventually) you want to be able to set more than one of them to `true` with OR or XOR math.